# Installation without makefiile - error: No targets specified and no makefile found

Tags: make

I am trying to install the following piece of software: https://github.com/linron84/JST

I cloned the repo to my computer, changed into the directory and tried to execute 'make' to install the software. There is no makefile and installation failed ("make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.")

However, the instructions specifically and only say:

> COMPILING:
>   Type "make" in a shell.

Is this a problem on the software side, or is there anything that I can do to install the software? Thank you!

**Edit: Solution**: 
Bodo correctly pointed out the makefile is in the subfolder 'Debug'. running make from there worked perfectly.

---

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-54-generic

Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Either a bug in the documentation or a missing `makefile` in the top level directory. Subdirectory `Debug` contains a `makefile`. Try `cd Debug; make`.

Comment: oh wow, I had only looked for it in src... You are marvelous, thank you!

Comment: @Bodo - you may want to copy your comment into the answer so that the question gets marked as having an answer and maybe Nikos will also accept it and you'll get the points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be either a bug in the documentation or a missing `makefile` in the top level directory. Subdirectory `Debug` contains a `makefile`. Try

```
cd Debug; make
```